# Looping over list of dataframes to dynamically create new columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops

Im working on a dataset that will allow me to assess various customer behaviours. To do this, I am reading in several excel files into a list before concatenating them into a single dataframe. Before this step though, I am wanting to create several new columns in each of them to summarise revenue based on year and product, similar to the below:

**Input Data**

```
| |Year     |Customer |Product  |PO       |Revenue  |
| |:--------|:--------|:--------|:--------|:--------|
|0| 2019    | Cust 1  | DIGITAL |  P1     |  100    |
|1| 2020    | Cust 1  | DIGITAL |  P2     |  120    |
|2| 2019    | Cust 2  | STORE   |  P3     |  240    |
|3| 2019    | Cust 1  | DIGITAL |  P4     |  200    |
|4| 2019    | Cust 2  | DIGITAL |  P5     |  110    |
|5| 2020    | Cust 2  | STORE   |  P6     |  100    |
|6| 2020    | Cust 3  | DIGITAL |  P7     |  120    |
|7| 2020    | Cust 3  | STORE   |  P8     |  180    |
```

**Desired Output**

```
| |Year     |Customer |Product  |PO       |Revenue  |19 Total |20 Total |19 Dig   |20 Dig   |19 Store |20 Store 
| |:--------|:--------|:--------|:--------|:--------|:--------|:--------|:--------|:--------|:--------|:--------
|0| 2019    | Cust 1  | DIGITAL |  P1     |  100    |  100    |         |  100    |         |         |  
|1| 2020    | Cust 1  | DIGITAL |  P2     |  120    |         |  120    |         |  120    |         |         
|2| 2019    | Cust 2  | STORE   |  P3     |  240    |  240    |         |         |         |  240    |  
|3| 2019    | Cust 1  | DIGITAL |  P4     |  200    |  200    |         |  200    |         |         |  
|4| 2019    | Cust 2  | DIGITAL |  P5     |  110    |  110    |         |  110    |         |         |
|5| 2020    | Cust 2  | STORE   |  P6     |  100    |         |  100    |         |         |         |  100    
|6| 2020    | Cust 3  | DIGITAL |  P7     |  120    |         |  120    |         |  120    |         |  
|7| 2020    | Cust 3  | STORE   |  P8     |  180    |         |  180    |         |         |         |  180    |
```

So basically each year will have its yearly total, as well as a revenue amount under the product category as well. Note, maintaining the order of the columns or rows is now needed.

Any help you can give will be great - let me know if anything doesn't make sense.

**EDIT**
In working through a few options, I have found the below code works, but am confident that there is a cleaner way of writing it if anyone can help?

```
df_2019 = df.loc[df['Year'] == 2019]
df_2020 = df.loc[df['Year'] == 2020]

df_list = [df_2019, df_2020]

for i in df_list:
  i[str(i['Year'].min())+' Total Rev'] = i['Revenue']
  i[str(i['Year'].min())+' Dig Rev'] = i.loc[i['Product'] == 'DIGITAL', 'Revenue']
  i[str(i['Year'].min())+' Store Rev'] = i.loc[i['Product'] == 'STORE', 'Revenue']

df_combined = pd.concat(df_list).sort_index()
             
df_combined
```

Answer (score 1):

We can `pivot_table` twice, then flatten your MultiIndex with list comprehension and finally use `pd.concat` to create your final dataframe:

```
piv1 = df.pivot_table(
    index=["PO"], 
    columns='Year', 
    values="Revenue"
).reset_index(drop=True).add_suffix(" Total")

piv2 = df.pivot_table(
    index=["PO"], 
    columns=["Year", "Product"], 
    values="Revenue"
).reset_index(drop=True)
piv2.columns = [f"{c1} {c2}" for c1, c2 in piv2.columns]

df = pd.concat([df, piv1, piv2], axis=1)
```

```
   Year Customer  Product  PO  Revenue  2019 Total  2020 Total  2019 DIGITAL  \
0  2019   Cust 1  DIGITAL  P1      100       100.0         NaN         100.0   
1  2020   Cust 1  DIGITAL  P2      120         NaN       120.0           NaN   
2  2019   Cust 2    STORE  P3      240       240.0         NaN           NaN   
3  2019   Cust 1  DIGITAL  P4      200       200.0         NaN         200.0   
4  2019   Cust 2  DIGITAL  P5      110       110.0         NaN         110.0   
5  2020   Cust 2    STORE  P6      100         NaN       100.0           NaN   
6  2020   Cust 3  DIGITAL  P7      120         NaN       120.0           NaN   
7  2020   Cust 3    STORE  P8      180         NaN       180.0           NaN   

   2019 STORE  2020 DIGITAL  2020 STORE  
0         NaN           NaN         NaN  
1         NaN         120.0         NaN  
2       240.0           NaN         NaN  
3         NaN           NaN         NaN  
4         NaN           NaN         NaN  
5         NaN           NaN       100.0  
6         NaN         120.0         NaN  
7         NaN           NaN       180.0
```

Comment: Thanks Erfan, appreciate you coming back to me on this - the issue I have is my main dataset is actually approx 70 columns and, while I don't need to preserve order, I do need to ensure that they are all included